# Typescript sourcemaps using command-line Babel

Tags: javascript, typescript, babeljs, tsc

I'm trying to get Babel to produce sourcemaps when run from the command line. The [Babel docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/options/) around sourcemaps seem to be targeted more toward the gulp workflow and I'm not sure how that translates to the command line.

I'm compiling my typescript using

```
tsc -p ./src
```

My tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "amd",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "out": "wwwroot/app.js",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "ES6"
    },
    "files": [
        "App.ts"
    ]
}
```

This produces wwwroot/app.js and wwwroot/app.js.map.

I then run babel over app.js:

```
babel ./wwwroot/app.js -o ./wwwroot/app.js --presets es2015 --compact false --inputSourceMap ./wwwroot/app.js.map --sourceMaps both
```

This modifies app.js, but leaves app.js.map in its original state, meaning the two no longer line up.

How do I get the babel step to produce a new sourcemap that maps my final app.js back to my typescript source?

Comment: The command line flags I was using were incorrect. Rather than --sourceMaps, I needed to be using --source-maps. "--input-source-map" doesn't appear to be present on the command line though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was looking for exactly the same thing and found this: https://phabricator.babeljs.io/T6911

Basically, while advanced options can also be used with `babel --name=value`, specifying a filename for inputSourceMap is not supported from the CLI and is only available when using the code.

[Gulp sourcemaps with TypeScript and Babel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33817841/gulp-sourcemaps-with-typescript-and-babel) might be helpful for you.  I can get it to generate sourcemaps that reference both the JS and original TS files which seems promising.  However (as mentioned in the comments of that answer) I also can't seem to get it to use the correct sourceRoot, so the .js.map files point to source locations that don't actually exist.

Not very satisfactory.  :-(

Comment: I ended up using a combination of command-line tsc for TS transpilation and gulp for babel and sourcemapping.
My tsconfig.json contains '"sourceMap": true', then gulp is run as a postbuild step loading the TS sourcemaps as input using sourcemaps.init({ loadMaps: true })

Comment: I got around the incorrect sourceRoot issue by including the source within the sourcemaps themselves (this is the default behaviour of gulp-sourcemaps)

Comment: "inputSourceMap is not supported from the CLI" is the accepted answer to my original question :)

Answer (score 7):

Here's how I made it work. In your tsconfig.json you'll need the following options:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true
  }
}
```

Then when you run babel-cli, you'll need to pass `--source-maps inline`. Here's an example npm script that assumes tsc outputs to a `build` directory and that babel will output to the same directory:

`tsc && babel build -d build --source-maps inline`

Comment: This works! But I'm curious how it actually works. Does Babel take inlined sourcemaps in files compiled by `tsc` as input then write its own sourcemaps? What if I don't have `inlineSources` and `inlineSourceMap` set in tsconfig.json?